# XSLT to pass value with XML tag

Tags: xslt, xquery

I need to get the value of a node with an xml format but all i'm getting is the values inside those tags.

Body:

```
<input>
<first>one</first>
<second>two</second>
<third>three</third>
</input>
```

XQuery

```
<PayloadAsMessage>
          <xsl:value-of select="/input"/>
</PayloadAsMessage>
```

Expected output:

```
<PayloadAsMessage>
        <first>one</first>
        <second>two</second>
        <third>three</third>
</PayloadAsMessage>
```

What i'm getting:

```
<PayloadAsMessage>
        onetwothree
</PayloadAsMessage>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:value-of` takes the string value of an element (it's also XSLT, not XQuery). To copy the XML exactly, use either `xsl:copy-of` (XSLT 1) or `xsl:sequence` (XSLT2).

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/input/*"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:sequence select="/input/*"/>
```